# Is there a way for the fee payer to be another account web3py

Tags: ethereum, web3py, erc20

Is it possible on the ETH chain to have a transaction signed by account_1 but send it and pay fee by account_2?

i know this is possible in solana but i cant find an answer in Ethereum.

What i would like to do is to sent some ERC20 Token, from account_1 to account_2 without having to send eth to account_2.

```py
# Fetch the token balance    
token_balance = contract.functions.balanceOf(acc2).call()

# Contract Address
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=USDT_CONTRACT_ADDRESS, abi=abi, )
# SEtting the acc_1 as the default account for the Web3 Instance
contract.web3.eth.default_account = acc1
web3.eth.default_account = acc1_eth.address

gasPrice = web3.eth.gasPrice

tx = contract.functions.approve(acc1, token_balance).buildTransaction({
    'from': acc2,
    'nonce': web3.eth.getTransactionCount(acc2),
    "gasPrice": gasPrice, 
    "chainId": 1
})

# Prior to this line, i get:
## {'code': -32000, 'message': 'gas required exceeds allowance (0)'}
# i cant set the gasPrice to 0 becaue then i will get `ContractLogicError`

signed_tx = acc2_eth.sign_transaction(tx)

a = web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
tx_receipt = web3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(a)

print(f"TXID => { tx_receipt.transactionHash.hex() }")
```

P.D., i do own private keys from both accounts but one is going to be disposable thats why i dont want to give it any ETH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible on the ETH chain to have a transaction signed by account_1 but send it and pay fee by account_2?

No it's not.